# Why " provided $t$ is not in $\theta$ " at the end of the definition of $\forall $ Intro Rule ? ( Shapiro's Entry On Classical Logic in SEP)

Tags: logic, soft-question

Here is the passage :

> "The introduction clause for the universal quantifier is a bit more
> complicated. Suppose that a sentence θ contains a closed term t, and
> that θ has been deduced from a set of premises Γ. If the closed term t
> does not occur in any member of Γ, then θ will hold no matter which
> object t may denote. That is, ∀vθ
>
> follows.
>
> ```
> (∀I)
> ```
>
> For any closed term t, if Γ⊢θ(v|t), then Γ⊢∀vθ provided that t is not
> in Γ or θ".

**First point** :
Something I do not understand is that the preliminary remark suggests that $t$ is contained in $\theta$ while the official statement of the rule requires this  not to be the case.

**Second point** :
Also, **should we not have** :

**If, for any closed term $t$,  $\Gamma |-\theta(v,t) $, then $\Gamma |- \forall v\theta$**

instead of

For any closed term t, if Γ⊢θ(v|t), then Γ⊢∀vθ ?

I mean, in order the universal statement to be deduced, should it not be required that the substitution works for any closed term? ( It seems to me that in the official rule,  " for any closed term" applies to the whole conditional, not to the antecedent in particular.)

Does the alternative reading I suggest make any difference? What do I miss?

Comment: The first two occurrences of $\theta$ in the passage you quoted seem to actually refer to $\theta(v|t)$.  The idea is that this sentence should contain $t$ only at those places where it was substituted for $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\theta$ might be $v=t$. Then $\theta(v|t)$ is $t=t$ and certainly provable. That doesn't mean that $\forall v\, v=t$ is true.

We might have $t=0$ in $\Gamma$. Then if $\theta$ is $v=0$, we have that $\theta(v|t)$ is $t=0$ and we certainly have $\Gamma\vdash \theta(v|t)$, but not $\forall v\,v=0$.